# "Ones" after the numeral

Tags: numbers

Is it necessary to put a "ones" after "200" in this sentence?

> The most interesting is that you can attach more than 10 photos to the
>   wall post — up to 200 (ones)!

Comment: The most interesting what? There needs to be a noun here; for example, "The most interesting **thing** is...".

Comment: So "interesting" cannot be a subject, yes?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Can't the subject be implicit? "The new wall post has useful features. The most interesting (one) is that you can...", i.e. isn't "one" optional here ?

Comment: @jlliagre in that context, yes; but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The most interesting is that you can attach more than 10 photos to the wall post — up to 200 (ones)! -**is incorrect.**
>
> The most interesting **thing** is that you can attach more than 10 photos to the wall post --up to 200 - **is correct.**

The word *ones* we use to describe *those ones* in particular.

> I have seen all 200 photos of yours on Facebook. Those **ones** are really nice.

Comment: Not me, but possibly because you didn't make clear what is correct? OP doesn't seem to mind though.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it not necessary, it is indeed wrong.